# Rabbet/rebate on window frames - cleaning them out. Is there a specialized plane for this?

Tags: tool-selection, hand-planing

I was using a block plane and chisel + sander to clean out rabbets for new panes of glass in wooden storm windows.

The block plane didn't clean completely into the corners, and got me wondering if there is a plane that takes care of both "sides" of a rabbet AND the corner simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

It is not usual to use planes for this. Window rabbets are normally cleaned by scraping since the surface does not need to be 'perfect'.

> a plane that takes care of both "sides" of a rabbet AND the corner simultaneously?

I don't think such a plane is made. The sides of rabbets require a [side rabbet plane](https://www.inthewoodshop.com/ToolReviews/TheVeritasSideRabbetPlane.html):

[image: side rabbet planes]

And to plane into a corner requires a chisel plane:

[image: Chisel plane]

Answer (score 0):

> wondering if there is a plane that takes care of both "sides" of a rabbet AND the corner simultaneously?

Rabbet planes and combination planes typically have a "spur" or "nicker" blade that scores the wood vertically in the corner of the rabbet just ahead of the iron, preventing tearout. The nicker helps to ensure that both the side and the corner of the rabbet are cut cleanly.